# Modules vs. Classes and their influence on descendants of ActiveRecord::Base

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, oop

Here's a Ruby OO head scratcher for ya, brought about by this Rails scenario:

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many(:prices)
  # define private helper methods 
end

module PrintProduct
  attr_accessor(:isbn)
  # override methods in ActiveRecord::Base
end

class Book < Product
  include PrintProduct
end
```

`Product` is the base class of all products. Books are kept in the `products` table via STI. The `PrintProduct` module brings some common behavior and state to descendants of `Product`. `Book` is used inside `fields_for` blocks in views. This works for me, but I found some odd behavior:

- After form submission, inside my controller, if I call a method on a book that is defined in `PrintProduct`, and that method calls a helper method defined in `Product`, which in turn calls the `prices` method defined by `has_many`, I'll get an error complaining that `Book#prices` is not found.

Why is that? Book is a direct descendant of Product!

More interesting is the following..

As I developed this hierarchy `PrintProduct` started to become more of an abstract `ActiveRecord::Base`, so I thought it prudent to redefine everything as such:

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
end

class PrintProduct < Product
end

class Book < PrintProduct
end
```

All method definitions, etc. are the same. In this case, however, my web form won't load because the attributes defined by `attr_accessor` (which are "virtual attributes" referenced by the form but not persisted in the DB) aren't found. I'll get an error saying that there is no method `Book#isbn`. Why is that?? I can't see a reason why the `attr_accessor` attributes are not found inside my form's `fields_for` block when `PrintProduct` is a class, but they are found when `PrintProduct` is a `Module`.

Any insight would be appreciated. I'm dying to know why these errors are occurring!

Comment: ever figure this out?  I am running into during my rails 3 port.

Answer (score 0):

You might have better luck delaying the `attr_accessor` call in `PrintProduct` until mixin-time:

```
module PrintProduct
  def self.included(base)
    base.attr_accessor :isbn
  end
  # other instance methods here
end
```

The problem is likely something to do with timing of the `attr_accessor` call and how that applies to modules mixed in. I'm not certain that the timing is defined by the Ruby spec, so it might vary betweeen implementations or versions.

Comment: When PrintProduct is a module the attr_accessor declaration of #isbn works as expected. When PrintProduct is changed to a class #isbn is not found. Perhaps it would work if I did as you said using self.extended, but that's not the issue. I'm wondering why these errors occur because there doesn't seem to be anything "wrong" with either design (or maybe there is, and that's why the errors are occurring). Anyhow, thanks for the answer!